# Can I get a Cucumber feature and its steps from a variable?

Tags: java, cucumber

I'm new to BDD and particularly Cucumber.

Can I get a features and its steps from a variable? Also, I want to get a feature and its steps from a test tracker (TestRail) before running tests by the special selection of this tests, and put it in a list, then one by one get a scenario and run it.

Is there such a possibility? Should I use Cucumber or another framework for this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that question but I think the answer is no. You can have steps that contain a variable by using a regex in the step definition. You can have a scenario outliine that parameterizes the test inputs. But there is no parameter that can contain a step. There is no concept of selection statements in Gherkin.

Comment: No exactly. I want to get scenario not from files, but from test tracker, by getting it from to variable. If cucumber can't do that, is there any other framework that can?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't define a Cucumber scenario in code (or at least not in a supported way). But if you were going to write code to get a scenario and its steps from your test tracker and run it, you could equally well write code to put the scenario and its steps in files and run the scenario with the cucumber executable.

I don't know of a Java testing framework in which you can define tests dynamically. You could do that in Ruby with RSpec or (less cleanly) minitest. But I don't know whether a Ruby test framework would be acceptable, or whether it would be OK for the people writing entries in your test tracker to have to read and/or write RSpec examples. (It seems strange to have Cucumber step definitions in a test tracker, too; having features in a test tracker seems more reasonable, aside from the question of how to run them.)

Comment: I rewrote feature builder and gherkin parser, so, now it works just as planed. Technically I can get future from variable, from whatever I want, if you interesting it. Thanks for feed!